# Using wildcard in Nano text editor?

Tags: replace, find, wildcard, nano

I have a document with multiple terms contained within quotations ("). For example, "1" 2 "3". I'd like to find and replace (^W, ^R) only the terms inside quotations. In my example, I'd like to find/replace "1" and "3".

I imagine I'd use a wildcard operator but cannot find one within nano.

How can I accomplish this goal?
Thanks!

Comment: There's no such thing as "bash nano". nano is not part of bash -- it can be run without even having bash installed.

Comment: (also, nano is an *extremely* limited-capability editor, designed for simplicity above all else; it may have regex support, but if it doesn't, I wouldn't be surprised -- consider learning emacs or vim).

Answer (score 1):

Begin an instance of "search and replace" with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> and then enable regex with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.
Enter the expression of what you'd like to replace (use your favorite search engine to [learn more about regex](https://ryanstutorials.net/regular-expressions-tutorial/regular-expressions-basics.php) or even check your work with [regex101](https://regex101.com)).

A lot of people tend to hate on nano, but I've yet to encounter a moment where it couldn't do what vim/emacs could do in terms of editing. Learn what you can from all of them, use your favorite.